# kotlin with jooq and write table models manually without code generation

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

I'm experimenting with jOOQ and Kotlin and seen some tutorials and docs and it looks really nice.

But if there is something very annoying with jOOQ is the code generation. It seems too complex, and eventually impossible to maintain. I decided to create my own table models (similar to how hibernate works).

I created two table models:

**User**

```
data class User(
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    val name: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String? = null
) {
    companion object {
        val TABLE: Table<Record> = DSL.table("user")
        val ID: Field<String> = DSL.field("id", String::class.java)
        val USER_NAME: Field<String> = DSL.field("user_name", String::class.java)
        val EMAIL: Field<String> = DSL.field("email", String::class.java)
        val PASSWORD: Field<String> = DSL.field("password", String::class.java)
    }
}
```

**Followers**

```
data class Followers(
    val id: String,
    val followerId: String,
    val userId: String
) {
    companion object {
        val TABLE: Table<Record> = DSL.table("followers")
        val ID: Field<String> = DSL.field("id", String::class.java)
        val FOLLOWER_ID: Field<String> = DSL.field("follower_id", String::class.java)
        val USER_ID: Field<String> = DSL.field("user_id", String::class.java)
    }
}
```

When I did some trivial SQL statements and it worked perfectly, but when I tried the next statement, I'm getting exception.

```
return dsl.select().from(u.TABLE)
            .rightJoin(f.TABLE).on(u.ID.eq(f.FOLLOWER_ID))
            .where(u.ID.eq(id)).fetch().into(User::class.java)
```

The expected statement from this code is:

```
select *
from user u
right outer join followers f
on u.id = f.follower_id
where u.id = 'e30919bf-5f76-11e8-8c96-701ce7e27f83';
```

But the statement I got from this code is:

```
select *
from user
  right outer join followers
  on id = follower_id
where id = 'e30919bf-5f76-11e8-8c96-701ce7e27f83'
```

And of course, this givse me (rightfully) the error  **Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous**

It raises a few questions:

1. Is there a better way to declare table model without code generation.
2. Why the DSL `select` does not transform to proper SQL statement? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### First off, some word of advice on your reluctance to use code generation:

> i seems too complex, and eventually impossible to maintain.
>   so, i decided to create my own table models (similar to how hibernate works).

You're (probably) going down a long path of pain and suffering. First off, you will already now need to think of database migrations, which are best done using your database's DDL language. This means, your database model of your data should be more important to you in the long run, than your client model. In fact, your client model is a copy of your database model, not something you'd like to maintain independently. With this mindset, it is more reasonable to have a code generator generate your client model from the database model, not vice versa.

Sure, Hibernate makes the client first approach easy as well, when you start a project. Yet, once you go to production, you *will* have to migrate your database, and then this model will break. You're back to database first, and it's worth setting up everything already now.

So, no. Code generation might introduce some complexity *now*, but it will be *much more easy to maintain* down the road, than you creating your own table models.

[I've written up a longer blog post about this topic, here](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/06/06/truth-first-or-why-you-should-mostly-implement-database-first-designs/).

#### Regarding your specific questions:

> ```
> return dsl.select().from(u.TABLE)
>           .rightJoin(f.TABLE).on(u.ID.eq(f.FOLLOWER_ID))
>           .where(u.ID.eq(id)).fetch().into(User::class.java)
> ```
>
> the expected statement from this code is: [...]

Well, that depends on what `u` and `f` are. You cannot just rename your Kotlin references to your table and expect jOOQ to know what they mean. I.e. you probably created the references as follows:

```
val u = User.TABLE;
val f = Follower.TABLE;
```

If that's how you created the reference, then the two things are the *same thing* by identity. jOOQ doesn't magically reverse engineer your Kotlin code to find out that you meant to *alias* your table. You have to tell jOOQ:

```
val u = User.TABLE.as("u");
val f = Follower.TABLE.as("f");
```

But now you're not done. You constructed the `User.TABLE` reference using the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), which means that jOOQ's runtime has no idea about the columns in that table. You cannot reference those columns anymore from the aliased table, because the type of the aliased table for plain SQL tables is `Table<?>`, not `User`.

You could, of course, create `TableImpl` instances and register all columns inside of your `TableImpl` instance - just like the code generator does. In that case, you would have tables *and* columns associated with them, and could use them type safely even with aliased tables.

All of this stuff is handled automatically by generated code, which again, I recommend you use with jOOQ. The main reason why anyone would not use the code generator with jOOQ is because the data model is dynamic, i.e. not known at compile time. Otherwise, you're just going to repeat tons of work that the code generator already does for you, automatically. And, as mentioned before, you will have much more work later on, when you start migrating your schema.

Comment: thank you for your advice and the fully answered question. I can understand better now the power of JOOQ code generation and its importance.

Comment: @LukasEder what would be a way to solve the problem without code generation? Doing a `.as(…)` with a qualified name in the `on` clause doesn't work because it places backticks around the aliased names.

Comment: @OriPopowski: Can you please ask a new question with more details?

Comment: @LukasEder sorry to hijack through comment. I saw you are very well familiarized with jooq. I really want to master it through maven plugin usage, flyway execution first all based using spring boot. Can you share/recommend any training course, video or manual to learn it? I find the official documentation kinda annoying to use and navigate. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @FedericoPiazza: Thanks for your message. It's not really related to this question or answer here, though. Feel free to send a message with some details about what you're looking for / what value that would add to your learning / what you find annoying in particular to the jOOQ mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user